# MySQL - How to find not Matching result from IN CLAUSE

Tags: mysql

I have below SQL statement which gives me not matching from table `tblscr_role` but I want to find out what is not matching from values of set of values in `NOT IN CLAUSE.9('ROLE1','ROLE2','ROLE3','ROLE4')`. How do I do that?

Below is my SQL example:

```
select role_name 
from tblscr_role 
where requestid = 9681 
and role NOT IN ('ROLE1','ROLE2','ROLE3','ROLE4')
```

Comment: I want to find out both side of not matching values. one from table not matching and one from IN CLAUSE NOT matching.

Comment: Sorry i can't understand what you want @Lord OfTheRing

Comment: What? Still don't get it. Please provide sample data and desired result to clear things up.

Comment: role cannot match any value in the IN clause, it is not just failing to match one of the values

Comment: I have set of role values e.g. ROLE1, ROLE2, ROLE3, ROLE4 in a string or Array. I want to check which values do not exist in database table tblscr_role. Is there anyway to find out using Query ? Or I have to write separate logic using PHP.

Comment: The problem you have is the data you want to return isn't stored in the database thus it can't return what's not there. By creating an inline view with the roles passed in, the system is able to return those values not in the database set.  A simple outer join between the inline view created and your base set can then return you the roles that don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're after something like this: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c157c/6/0)

We use an outer join to get the results from tblsrc_role and create an inline view for the roles you want to match to we then look at the roles both ways  All roles in tblsrc_role not in roles list and all roles in roles not in tblsrc_role  We then union those results together...

Normally this could be done with a FULL OUTER JOIN; but I don't believe mySQL supports them, thus the Left right and union to simulate a full outer join.

```
Select S1.role, B.Role, S1.RequestID 
from tblSrc_role S1
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT 'ROLE1' as role UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ROLE2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ROLE3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ROLE4') B
  on S1.Role = b.Role
WHERE S1.RequestID = 9681
UNION
Select S1.Role, B.role, S1.RequestID
from tblSrc_role S1
RIGHT JOIN 
( SELECT 'ROLE1' as role UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ROLE2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ROLE3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ROLE4') B
  on S1.Role = b.Role
  and S1.RequestID = 9681
```

If you want to find which ones in your list not in the system :

```
Select S1.Role, B.role, S1.RequestID
from tblSrc_role S1
RIGHT JOIN 
( SELECT 'ROLE1' as role UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ROLE2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ROLE3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ROLE4') B
  on S1.Role = b.Role
where s1.requestID is null
```

The problem you have is the data you want to return isn't stored in the database thus it can't return what's not there.  By creating an inline view, with the roles passed in, the system is able to return those values not in the existing set.  B.Role will contain the list of roles not in the system S1.Role and S1.RequestID will be null for those that don't exist.

Though you could just return B.Role to get the roles that don't exist.